# Best PHP mailing library for Codeigniter-2

Tags: codeigniter

Iam using CI-2 default mail class for sending emails. But it is not sending HTML based emails properly.

Can someone tell me good email sending libraries for CI2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by 'not sending HTML based emails properly'?

Comment: @Repox When I send email by using CI default email library. The email receives in gmail, just shows all text with html tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to configure the library to send html emails

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

gmail and HTML content is a common problem; solutions have been suggested in the official CI forum with references to using Swift Mailer instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution I've found for poor HTML / Email Support.

Open up the Email Class:

```
System/Libraries/Email.php
```

Around Line 51 You'll see

```
var $send_multipart = TRUE;
```

Set this to FALSE and try again. I find CI's email library to be very good.